# When should I include Content-Disposition header in a Partial-Content HTTP response?

Tags: java, http, httpserver, download

Should or shouldn't I include a `Content-Disposition` header in a `Partial-Content` response for a file download resumption?

When should I include it, when shouldn't I include it, in terms of the `Partial-Content` response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Resume file uploading process in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872784/how-to-resume-file-uploading-process-in-android)